# How to use map(func,iterator) function when func() do not return a value?

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming

Functions like print() do not return a value. But sometimes I do need to make iterations on them. Is there any method to code in a functional programming way instead of using "for"?

```
# changes some values of a list according to another pointer iterator.
thelist = [1]*100
slices = [(3,8),(9,15),(72,88)]
for items in slices:
    for i in range(items[0],items[1]):
        thelist[i] = 8
```

Here is the example, what I want is to change the value in "thelist". How to re-code by using comprehension or map() or something else, without losing the efficiency of the code.

Comment: " However, when move to python3, new list which occupies much space have to be generated." I don't understand what you mean. In Python 3, `map` returns a lazy iterator, wheras in Python 2, `map` returns a fully materialized `list`. What exactly is it that you can do in Python 2 that you cannot do in Python 3 without creating a new list?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry for my confusing words. I rewrite the question. Does it make sense to you now?

Comment: The answer is you *should not use functional constructs with side-effects like `print`*, or like in your example, mutating a list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is roughly equivalent to:

```
import itertools
slices = set(itertools.chain(*itertools.starmap(range, ((3,8),(9,15),(72,88)))))
thelist = map(lambda (x, y): y if x in slices else 8, enumerate(range(100)))
```

So there is a functional way of doing it, but i would not recommend in this case, **you should not use functional for side effects computations**

Comment: you'd be much better off making `slices` a `set`

Comment: @DanielSanchez Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also, without itertools:

```
thelist2 = map(lambda ix: 8 if any( (s[0] <= ix[0] < s[1] for s in slices) ) else ix[1], enumerate(thelist2))
```

But it is far less readable (IMHO). Also, see comment of Daniel Sanchez about side effect. Side effects are not in functional programming way...